# How to run material UI example snippets within a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

All I want to achieve is a page that has a header that reads: "Survey Start" and then a user select interface under that. I am envisioning a very simple component:

```
export class Survey extends Component {
    state = { 

     }

    render() { 

        return (
            <React.Fragment>

                <h2>Survey Start</h2>
                <Survey sorcery here>
            </React.Fragment>
)
}
```

Then my App.js runs this.

I aim to replace "survey sorcery" with the "some important helper text" version of MaterialUI's user select. I directly copied from the javascript source that was provided. Seen here:

https://material-ui.com/components/selects/

I thought it would be as simple as copying and pasting within my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';



export class Survey extends Component {
    state = { 

     }

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        formControl: {
          margin: theme.spacing(1),
          minWidth: 120,
        },
        selectEmpty: {
          marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        },
      }));
      
      export default function SimpleSelect() {
        const classes = useStyles();
        const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');
      
        const handleChange = (event) => {
          setAge(event.target.value);
        };
    }

    render() { 

        return (
            <React.Fragment>

                <h2>Survey Start</h2>
                    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">Age</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select-helper"
                    value={age}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    >
                    <MenuItem value="">
                    <em>None</em>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                    <FormHelperText>Some important helper text</FormHelperText>
                    </FormControl>
            </React.Fragment>

        );


    }
}
```

However this returned several errors, including citing the line where I defined `useStyles`:

> The 'const' modifier can only be used in Type Script files.

Not sure why it threw that since I was careful to click the javascript example file on the example source code.

### Question

How do I get the materialUI example user select to integrate with a vanilla component?

Comment: The problem is you are writing the component in class format and the material UI is in react hook format (functional components) . You can't use the functional component inside the class component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing components inside components.

Try to see [thinking in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) to get a better understanding of how component works. You need to export `<SimpleSelect />` as its own component, then use it in your `<Survey />` component.

Refactored code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 120
    },
    selectEmpty: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
    }
}));


function SimpleSelect() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = event => {
        setAge(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">Age</InputLabel>
            <Select
                labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
                id="demo-simple-select-helper"
                value={age}
                onChange={handleChange}
            >
                <MenuItem value="">
                    <em>None</em>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
            <FormHelperText>Some important helper text</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
    );
}


export class Survey extends Component {
    state = {};

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h2>Survey Start</h2>
                <SimpleSelect />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I finished a few tutorials but still not so intuitive sometimes. Thanks for the answer and link to thinking in react. Noticed it worked once I added `default` to the export statement, but could just be mine

Comment: without `default` export you can still [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) it, however it is within the curly braces. For instance, instead of `import Survey from Survey` it is `import { Survey } from Survey`. Thus you can export multiple not default components from one file